# How to determine machine architecture in Python?

Tags: python, cpu-architecture

I'm wondering how to find the architecture of the machine python is running on and save it to a string.
The only other example I've been able to find works only on Windows, and doesn't even detect the proper architecture if it's Windows on Arm. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
***NullUsxr***

Comment: What have you tried? Have you seen https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html?

Comment: It gives the wrong architecture type when ran on arm. The output of the universal command is `('64bit', '')`, despite my system architecture being aarch64.

Comment: Have you explored all the functions in the module? `platform.machine()` or `platform.processor()` seem like they might give you what you want?

Comment: `platform.machine()` surprisingly returns the correct value of 'arm64'! Thank you!

Comment: Do any of the answers on [Is there a reliable way to determine the system CPU architecture using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7491391) or [How can I return system information in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/466684) help?  or [How to collect current architecture in Python 3, in a way that is portable across Linux, Windows and MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64044020) ?

Comment: The question title is an obvious duplicate of those, so you need to be specific about *exactly* what you want to know.  e.g. for a 32-bit Python interpreter running on a 64-bit-capable system, do you want to know that the python interpreter is running in 32-bit mode (so if you want to load any binary DLLs, they need to match that), or do you want to know if you should start the 32 or 64-bit version of some other executable, if this is a wrapper / launcher for another program.  (Applicable to x86-64, or somewhat to ARM64 systems)

Comment: I temporarily closed the question so it doesn't collect answers that aren't what you're looking for.  If it's not a duplicate of an existing SO question, it can get reopened once you have some specific detail about what you want in various corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import platform
print(platform.system())
```

According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.system it says the function would "Returns the system/OS name, such as 'Linux', 'Darwin', 'Java', 'Windows'. An empty string is returned if the value cannot be determined."

Comment: Good idea, though it doesn't tell me if 'Darwin' or 'Windows', etc. is 32-bit, 64-bit, aarch64 and so on. Using `platform.architecture(executable=sys.executable, bits='', linkage='')` from the same source as yours, also returns an invalid value if on the aarch64 architecture.